# Why is transaction marked as invalid?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, parity

I am trying to create a transaction by sending 1 ether from one account to another. Currently, I'm running a local fully-synched parity node. It's running on the Volta test network of EWF (Energy Web Foundation). It's actually possible connecting to that node by Metamask and sending some Ether, but whenever I try that with the web3js which runs in a nodejs app, the parity node gives the following warning/output:

```
2019-10-25 00:56:50  jsonrpc-eventloop-0 TRACE own_tx  Importing transaction: PendingTransaction { transaction: SignedTransaction { transaction: UnverifiedTransaction { unsigned: Transaction { nonce: 1, gas_price: 60000000000, gas: 21000, action: Call(0x2fa24fee2643d577d2859e90bc6d9df0e952034c), value: 1000000000000000000, data: [] }, v: 37, r: 44380982720866416681786190614497685349697533052419104293476368619223783280954, s: 3058706309566473993642661190954381582008760336148306221085742371338506386965, hash: 0x31b4f889f5f10e08b9f10c87f953c9dfded5d0ed1983815c3b1b837700f43702 }, sender: 0x0b9b5323069e9f9fb438e89196b121f3d40fd56e, public: Some(0xa3fc6a484716b844f18cef0039444a3188a295811f133324288cb963f3e5a21dd6ee19c91e42fa745b45a3cf876ff04e0fd1d060ccfe1dab9b1d608dda4c3733) }, condition: None }
2019-10-25 00:56:50  jsonrpc-eventloop-0 DEBUG own_tx  Imported to the pool (hash 0x31b4f889f5f10e08b9f10c87f953c9dfded5d0ed1983815c3b1b837700f43702)
2019-10-25 00:56:50  jsonrpc-eventloop-0 WARN own_tx  Transaction marked invalid (hash 0x31b4f889f5f10e08b9f10c87f953c9dfded5d0ed1983815c3b1b837700f43702)
```

When I checked the balance of the accounts, nothing has happened. I've tried to increase gasPrice, adding a 'from' key/value pair to txObject, etc. I have also started parity node with `--no-persistent-txqueue` so that it doesn't cache too many of transactions, as it's suggested [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/7872). But that didn't change anything, either. So I still get the same error and transaction doesn't go through. What is causing this problem and how can I solve it?

```
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from, (err, txCount) => {
        const txObject = {
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
            from: from,
            to: to,
            value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(val, 'ether')),
            gas: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('60', 'gwei'))
        }

        // Sign the transaction
        const tx = new Tx(txObject);
        tx.sign(pk);
        const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
        const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');

        // Broadchast the transaction to the network
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
            if (txHash === undefined) {
                res.render('sendTransaction', {
                    txSuccess: 0,
                    blockHash: 'Hash Undefined'
                });
                res.end();;
            } else {
                res.render('sendTransaction', {
                    txSuccess: 1,
                    blockHash: txHash,
                });
                res.end();;
            }
        });
    });
```

Any suggestion is welcome,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine so it must be something small, you're very close!

- What does the `error` object contain in `web3.eth. sendSignedTransaction` callback?
- Check your `nonce` to make sure it has not been used yet. https://volta-explorer.energyweb.org/address/0x0b9b5323069e9f9fb438e89196b121f3d40fd56e/transactions shows a few transactions from the sender address, with "4" being next value for `nonce`
- Try generating the raw transaction via JavaScript and broadcasting it manually via command line